# Proof that the merit of a prime gap can become arbitary large?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

If $p_n$ denotes the $n$-th prime number, we can define $$g_n:=p_{n+1}-p_n$$ as the gap after the $n$-th prime number. The merit of a prime gap is defined as $$m(p_n):=\frac{g_n}{\ln(p_n)}$$

It is well known that the merit of a prime gap can become arbitary large.

> How can this however be proven ?

I do not think, it can be derived from the prime-number theorem. What else can we do ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap#Lower_bounds

Comment: There is [Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/08/21/large-gaps-between-consecutive-prime-numbers/) where he recommends to interpret $P(x)+1\ldots P(x)+x$ as generated by the image modulo $P(x) = \prod_{p \le x} p$ of the $\pi(x)$ residue classes $(0 \bmod p)$ and to do the same with "better residue classes" $(a_p \bmod p)$ obtaining a longer sequence $P(x)+c \ldots P(x)+d$ of composite numbers

Comment: At first blush, by Bertrand's postulate (and refinements for large $p$), $g_n<p_n$, meaning $m(p_n)<\frac{p_n}{ln(p_n)}$